# How can I specify criteria for filtering an existing UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Quick question. I have a button placed in one view controller, and a UITableView in another (it's already populated with custom cells containing title, description...etc). I want my users to be able to press the button, and have the UITableView appear with filtered results.

What would the code look like for that? How can I make this button filter my UITableView with specified criteria?

**Here's the code on the button's viewcontroller.m file:**

```
- (IBAction)buttonpressed:(UIButton *)sender {

        NSLog(@"Button Pushed!");



}
```

**And here's what my TableViewController.m file looks like:**

```
- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView: (UITableView *)tableview

{

    return 1;

}

- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [searchResults count];




    } else {
        return [Strains count];

    }



}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *strainTableIdentifier = @"StrainTableCell";

    StrainTableCell *cell = (StrainTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strainTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 


        cell = [[StrainTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:strainTableIdentifier];



        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StrainTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {


        cell.titleLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Description"];
        cell.ratingLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Rating"];


        NSLog(@"%@", searchResults);
    } else {
        cell.titleLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
         cell.descriptionLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Description"];
         cell.ratingLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Rating"];



    }


    {

    } 


return cell;

}
```

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the Table View Controller in the buttonpressed method (if you're using storyboards then you would connect the button to the second view controller and then do this in prepareForSegue, otherwise just create the instance of the view controller within button pressed and push it to the navigation controller).

Add a property or instance variable to the table view controller that specifies the filter you want to apply and set that when you create the table view controller, and then do the filtering in viewDidLoad and/or cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: That is a great guide, but I think she is looking for sample code.